# Training keras model; why mae decreases while mse increases?

Tags: neural-network, keras, regression, mse

I am training a model using keras on a regression problem. When I investigate the loss and metrics during training, sometimes `mean absolute error (mae)` decreases at the end of an epoch, while `mean square error (mse)` increases. I set `mae` as loss and `mse` as metric.

Is it OK? Or is there any problem with the setting?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSE and MAE are different metrics. A decrease in the one does not imply a decrease in the other. Consider the following toy example for the size-2 output values of a network with the target value as `Target:` [0,0]

- Timestep 1: `Output:` [2,2], `MAE:` 2, `MSE:` 4
- Timestep 2: `Output:` [0,3], `MAE:` 1.5, `MSE:` 4.5

So MAE decreased while MSE increased. Given that you are optimizing for MAE and only monitor MSE, your observation is perfectly fine and does not imply any problem.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the example. MAE and MSE should applied on the error. In T1: MAE: 1, MSE: 1. And in T2 MAE:1.5, MSE:2.5. So, both MAE and MSE increased.

Comment: Of course, thanks, I edited it. The target was wrong.

Comment: @KiraMichiru, if  my target is a single number: target = a, my prediction is p_a. MAE = abs(a - p_a) , MSE = (a - p_a)^2.  MAE and MSE should increase or decrease at the same time?

Comment: @scotthuang If you are only considering one datapoint with a single dimension, then you are right. However, what makes the **mean** in MAE and MSE meaningful is that they are usually applied to more than one datapoint, e.g. to all datapoints in an batch. Then, also if each data-point has a single dimension, the **averaging** operation between the different datapoints could lead to the same behavior as shown in the example.

Comment: @KiraMichiru,  got it. I forgot that even if i only have a number, but I actually calculate a batch of data.